# How to call prompt() or alert() in google app script for web apps?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, prompt

I am trying to develop a web service by means of Google appscript and I tried to call the ui.prompt() or Broswer.inputBox() function in the code. However, none of these method worked. The documentation of both of the two services seems to be limited to SpreadsheetApp class. So is there any way that I could call prompt() from the server side or is there any method to work the way around ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just call `alert()` or `prompt()` on the html side.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui), you're being given access to an API which allows integration with the Google Sheets web interface.

Alternatively, when you deploy an Apps Script project as a web application, you are responsible for delivering a UI by using the [`HTMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html) class. In addition to the reference documentation, there's also an [introductory guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) and [a list of best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices).

To answer your question about presenting an alert, here's a modified version of the first example from the best practices document:

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

#### Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript.html

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

If you populate an Apps Script project with those files, deploy it as a web application and visit the generated URL, the Javascript will be executed in the browser and an alert dialog will be presented.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

On Google Apps Script deployed as web applications, it's not possible , instead use HTML/CSS/JavaScript (including a libraries/frameworks)